# Is there a better package to publish to Aws Iot Core than AWSSDK.Iot using C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I am using the `awssdk.iot` nuget package for C#, and I cannot find a method to publish. I have found a method `Amazon.IoT.AmazonIoTClient(region).UpdateThing(UpdateThingRequest)` that states in the document that it "Updates the data for a thing."

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/IoT/TIoTClient.html

Where `Amazon.IoT.Model.UpdateThingRequest` has the properties `AttributePayload, ExpectedVersion, RemoveThingType, ThingName, ThingTypeName`. However, it does not have any properties that I can actually attach my data too. I can send attribute payloads, but this only attaches the attributes to the thing. I looked into `UpdateStream` but that updates iot from S3 files. 
Is there a better wat to publish?

```
using Amazon;

public static string Iot()
{
    var Region = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
    Amazon.IoT.Model.UpdateThingResponse response;

    using (var client = new Amazon.IoT.AmazonIoTClient(region: Region))
    {

        var request = new Amazon.IoT.Model.UpdateThingRequest();
        request.ThingName = name;
        request.AttributePayload = new Amazon.IoT.Model.AttributePayload();
        request.AttributePayload.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"data","myvalue"}
        };
        response = client.UpdateThing(request);

    }
    return response.HttpStatusCode.ToString() ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MQTT Publish messages are sent using the `AmazonIotDataClient`

The `Publish` and `PublishAsync` methods are available.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=IotData/MIotDataPublishAsyncPublishRequestCancellationToken.html&tocid=Amazon_IotData_AmazonIotDataClient the `PublishAsync` method:

> Initiates the asynchronous execution of the Publish operation.

Which uses the [PublishRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=IotData/TPublishRequest.html&tocid=Amazon_IotData_Model_PublishRequest) type. This has payload, QoS and topic fields.

Comment: Never commented but this is the correct solution. AWS has terrible documentation.